# Best modeling technique for multiple independent variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, prediction

I have time series data with 4 independent and 1 dependent variable. I'm trying to predict the value of the independent variable using the dependent variables. The data is quite complex, I've tried the linear regression already, which as expected did not work.

I proceeded to using multivariate polynomial regression, but have been unsuccessful till now because I haven't been able to get the code going. But I also read somewhere that using multivariate polynomial might not be the best approach.

Is there any other model that I could use to predict the value of the independent variable? My entire data is numerical, with new data coming in everyday. I'm using python for this exercise.

Any suggestions are helpful and highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe consider a multilayer neural network with rectified linear unit activations?This is a higher dimensional analogue of a spline curve. Each additional layer acts as another spline. If you make it deep, you get many splines.

This question is somewhat vague. What does your data look like? What does it represent?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and any information that you might have about the relationship between the dependent and independent data.